# ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Dockerfile multi stage build

Tags: reactjs, django, docker, deployment, dockerfile

I have made an app with the backend on django and react based frontend but inside a new separate django app. So I have to write a multi stage Dockerfile.

*[My project structure]*(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wqV9.png)

***Dockerfile:***

```
FROM python:3.10.6 as backend
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

FROM node:18-alpine as frontend
WORKDIR /app/frontend
COPY frontend/package.json ./package.json
COPY frontend/package-lock.json ./package-lock.json
RUN npm install
COPY frontend .
RUN npm run build

FROM python:3.10.6
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=backend /app .
# RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY --from=frontend /app/frontend ./frontend
CMD python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

***Docker Compose:***

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:15.3-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    ports:
      - "3000:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

***Error:***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
dental_clinic_app-backend-1  |   File "/app/manage.py", line 11, in main
dental_clinic_app-backend-1  |     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
dental_clinic_app-backend-1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

I have the virtual environment activated.I dont know enough about docker but i suspect its overwriting files in the third stage but i just cant figure out why. Or maybe it is something entirely unrelated?

**NOTE:** It works when I uncomment the line in the Dockerfile.

Comment: First of all you need to specify the django project folder for us is it  "api" or "dental_clinic_app"? also which line do you uncomment?

Comment: You copy the Django project to the production stage, you also need to copy your packages from the backend container.

Comment: @DrummerMann thanks for the help. By packages you mean the ones in requirements.txt ? I thought they were copied along with the rest of the project files. How do I copy them?

Comment: This article explains it: https://medium.com/@tech_with_mike/django-docker-optimization-with-multi-stage-technique-with-video-73d96669cd2e